# Is "one of my favorite author" correct?

Tags: grammaticality, singular-vs-plural

Does this sounds right? I’m taking about a book I like by an author I like!

> One of my favorite books by one of my favorite authors..

or

> One of my favorite books by one of my favorite author (this one sounds weird but idk)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simple calculation - when you say *one of something* means you have more than one of *that thing!*

> One of my friends ...

Obviously, it is *one of **many***, so, `one of my favorite authors`

In certain cases, yes, you can use *double* 'one of...' as in your example -

> This is one of my favorite books by one of my favorite authors

Without 's,' it would be ungrammatical.

Answer (score 0):

No. "One of" takes a list, so in this case it means "one author out of a list of authors". So it's plural.

If it would not be plural, that is, if you had only one favourite author, it would not have been a list and you could not have said "one of". Rather just "... by my favourite author".